# cannot resolve setselection() on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to put the cursor at the end of the text in the EditText but its doesn't want to recognise the EditText. Can anyone see a problem here?

```
txtEditDesc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus)
            {
                txtEditDesc.setSelection(txtEditDesc.getText().length());
                InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                assert imm != null;
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEditDesc"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtDesc"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_below="@+id/delResMod"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="15"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Can i see all of the java code?

Comment: clean and rebuild project than check

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with caching.

Try cleaning your project and see if that does it, if not try to delete the .idea folder, close and open project again and then sync gradle.

Answer (score -1):

Variable 'txtEditDesc'  does not looks like is instance of EditText.

Comment: If not not an instance of EditText then how the listener is attached?

Comment: For TextView instance also you could set the listener.

Comment: From screen short its clear that 'testEditDesc' is an instance of EditText Class

Comment: In the xml its being declared as EditText and there can be chance in Java he might have declared as TextView Instance.